# How to get keras model prediction for batch of images?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, keras-layer

Sorry about my english. I am new to the machine learning. I am using this code for predict the class of an image input.

```
def predict(self, imagePaths):
    classes_array=[]
    for i in imagePaths:
        print(i)
        image=(cv2.imread(i, 1))
        #new_image=cv2.resize(image,(100,100))
        #thr_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(new_image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,10)
        thr_image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
        predict_image=np.array(thr_image).reshape(-1, 100,100,3)     
        #Process predict image for prediction
        classes = model.predict_classes(predict_image)
        classes_array.append(classes)                              
    #Predicted label of image
    return classes_array
```

In here `imagePaths` is an array including image file paths that need to predict. This code give prediction for every image in `imagepaths` array. But I need to have one output class that suit most for whole batch of images. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: If I use "classes = model.predict(predict_image)"  it will give a np array. I can get the releavant class that has highest probability. But how can I get the accuracy or probability for that class from this array?

Comment: Can you please give information about the input shape of the model?

Comment: input shape is (100,100,3)

Comment: Have you tried using the mean or median or class with the highest occurrence?